# How to use external js in angular without adding in asset function

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to use external js in my angular project without adding it to asset `folder.js` contains namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [from-cdn package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/from-cdn)

this allows you to add external js/css to your components without adding it to the assets folder.

```
    import fromCDN from "from-cdn";

    fromCDN([
        "//cdn.some.com/a/a.js",
        "//cdn.some.com/a/b.js",
        "//cdn.some.com/a/a.css",
    ]).then( _ => alert("All is ready"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. You can create a test.js file in same component  and just use this code in your component.ts

ngOnInit() {  
  this.loadJsFile(FilEPath);  
}  
public loadJsFile(url) {  
  let node = document.createElement('script');  
  node.src = url;  
  node.type = 'text/javascript';  
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);  
}
```